# How to get the name of GNU install directories outside of CMake or make?

Tags: bash, cmake, gnu

I'm using CMake to install software as defined by GNUInstallDirs which in turn are supposed to follow [these standards](https://www.gnu.org/prep/standards/html_node/Directory-Variables.html).

It turns out that these are not entirely uniform across distributions however - `libdir` becomes `lib` under ubuntu whereas under alpine it resolves to `lib64`.

I need to reference these directories outside of CMake in a portable manner - specifically I'm adding a path containing `libdir` to `$PYTHONPATH` in a bash script.

**How can I find the actual directory name that `libdir` is resolving to on the current system within bash?**

Comment: Would it be acceptable to have the installation print this value somewhere in the file system?

Comment: That would work, but it would not be as clean as I would like it to be. I could imagine generating a bash script within CMake that exports these values and could then be sourced.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Criteria using which the module `GNUInstallDirs` chooses between `lib` and `lib64` are [described](https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/blob/master/Modules/GNUInstallDirs.cmake#L216) in the module itself:

```
  # Override this default 'lib' with 'lib64' iff:
  #  - we are on Linux system but NOT cross-compiling
  #  - we are NOT on debian
  #  - we are on a 64 bits system
  # reason is: amd64 ABI: https://github.com/hjl-tools/x86-psABI/wiki/X86-psABI
  # For Debian with multiarch, use 'lib/${CMAKE_LIBRARY_ARCHITECTURE}' if
  # CMAKE_LIBRARY_ARCHITECTURE is set (which contains e.g. "i386-linux-gnu"
  # and CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX is "/usr"
  # See http://wiki.debian.org/Multiarch
```

In a simple form, your Python script could check:

1. Whether it runs on 64-bit Linux.
2. Whether it runs on Debian-based OSes.

If the first check is true but the second is false, then `libdir` is `lib64/`.
Otherwise `libdir` is `lib/`.

### Alternative. Searching for the library

Your script could check whether `lib/` or `lib64/` contains a specific library, and for `$PYTHONPATH` chose the directory which actually contains a library.

This approach has an advantage, that it is safe against (future) changing rules in `GNUInstallDirs` module for select between `lib/` and `lib64/`.

### Alternative. Shipping your installation with an information about installing dirs

When install your project, you could also create a file which contains value of `CMAKE_INSTALL_FULL_LIBDIR` variable, so this value could be extracted by your Python script. As for the file which contains this information, it could be stored under predefined directory: e.g. `datarootdir` is always a `share/`.

This approach has an advantage, that it works even when the value for `libdir` differs from both `lib/` and `lib64/`.

Comment: That is a very helpful and comprehensive overview, thank you. Your third approach sounds like the most portable.

Comment: Maybe to add to these options: Another possibility I have been tinkering with is to actively query the value of `CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR` at the time of adding to `PYTHONPATH` with something along the line of `echo "include(GNUInstallDirs)\nmessage(\${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR})\n" | cmake -P /dev/stdin`, but it appears like cmake cannot read from stdin in this way.


It works fine as `echo "include(GNUInstallDirs)\nmessage(\${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR})\n" > /tmp/gnuinstall && cmake -P /tmp/gnuinstall`

Comment: You could add your own answer as well. No needs to collect **all** possible solutions in a single answer post.

Answer (score 0):

To add a further alternative to [Tsyvarev's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67720256/13128825):

## Return the dir name from CMake on demand

At time of referring to the installed path, we can get the specific directory by printing the variable from within CMake itself:

```
echo "include(GNUInstallDirs)\nmessage(\${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR})\n" > /tmp/gnuinstall &&
cmake -P /tmp/gnuinstall
```